# solaris 11.3 first time login

Tags: solaris, password

Dears, 
I just installed solaris ios on vmware and wanted to know the very first credentials to log into the system 
i assume the user is solaris but tried root or solaris for the password but with no success

EDIT: adding a picture of the first booting of the solaris on vmware

[image]

Comment: At install time you were prompted to set up users and passwords. There is no default password for root in Solaris.

Comment: And root in Solaris 11 is a role, not account. So you can execute things with such (root) privileges, but you can't su to root

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I just updated the question with the screenshot when I first try to install solaris on vmware

Comment: Did you install Solaris from a prebuilt virtual machine, or did you go through the typical procedure where you boot from an ISO image and answer a bunch of configuration questions?

Answer (score 2):

As noted by @schaiba and @Romeo Ninov, for the initial install for Solaris 11, root is created as a role.  But the install process also asks you for an initial user which it will create with "admin" privs.  Using this initial account you can use su or sudo to assume the root role.

Let's confirm the RBAC settings for root.

As you can see, the type is a role.
And it's set to use the users authentication (pw) to assume the role.  Which allows us to not have to manage a root passwd.

[4] `getent user_attr root`
root::::**roleauth=user**;**type=role**;auths=solaris.*;profiles=All;audit_flags=lo:no;lock_after_retries=no;min_label=admin_low;clearance=admin_high

Answer (score 1):

At the first time the user root has the same password as the user created in the installation process, to change the password root You must open a terminal and type su root then type the password of the user create during installation, You should the message "Password for user 'root' has expired" then type the new password

Answer (score 0):

That happens when you use the Automated Install; use "root" as the login and "solaris" as the password.